# Calling a custom method from a datagridview column expression

Tags: c#, datagridview, methods, expression

using c#, vs2008 winforms

I have a datagridview that i am programtically binding to a binding source, that is bound to a dataset with 1 table.

After filling the dataset using the sqlAdaptor, i want to add a new column to the dataset, and in the new column populate it with a result derived from a call to a custom method in the form.

Code Eg is bellow but i get a "Expression contains undefined function call this.Test()

Is it allowed to call methods as such in the expression of the column

thanks in advance for any help
cheers

```
this.dsProdOrdLst1.ProdOrder.Columns.Add("sOrderType", typeof(string), 
    "this.Test(order_type)"); // order_type is another column in the dataset
```

elsewhere in the form class is the method

```
public int Test(int orderType)
{
    return 10; //return a test value
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AFAIK, these expressions (known as [ADO.NET expressions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms810291.aspx)) have no way of calling any kind of user defined functions. It should however by trivial to manually populate the new column:

```
this.dsProdOrdLst1.ProdOrder.Columns.Add("sOrderType", typeof(string));

foreach (DataRow row in dsProdOrdLst1.ProdOrder.Rows)
{
    row["sOrderType"] = Test((int) row["order_type"]);
}
```

Alternatively, you might be able to implement your entire function in an ADO.NET expression, but you really only want to do this for *very* simple functions, as otherwise it will be a mess:

```
IIF(order_type = 0, 'Mail', IIF(order_type = 1, 'Phone', 'Online'))
```

The documentation of [`DataColumn.Expression`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datacolumn.expression.aspx) has a list of supported functions (scroll pretty far down to find it).

Comment: Yeah, i wanted to avoid that by doing it in expressions i thought it would be faster as it would execute on each row, rather than having to iterate through the whole dataset. Well nevermind if its not possible its not possible